# Why Ant Design for Angular has grid directives instead of just components

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

```
 <div nz-row nzType="flex" nzJustify="center" nzAlign="top">
    <div nz-col nzSpan="4"><p class="height-100">col-4</p></div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="4"><p class="height-50">col-4</p></div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="4"><p class="height-120">col-4</p></div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="4"><p class="height-80">col-4</p></div>
  </div>
```

This code from Ant design component library is using `nz-col` as directive. Can somebody explain why it is used as directive instead of component? Any significance of using as directive?

Comment: From reading the source code, it simply extends the component https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/a51694983ea886c5d54623d14534bd68a2b7df98/components/grid/nz-col.directive.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the source code of **[`NzColDirective`](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/grid/nz-col.directive.ts)**, it `extends` the **[`NzColComponent`](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/grid/nz-col.component.ts)** class.

`NzColComponent` essentially to have access to things like `@Host` Component, the `@Host` Directive, `ElementRef` etc, is relying on `NzColDirective` and is eventually taking it from there as `NzColDirective` essentially calls `super` in it's constructor and passes it all those properties.